# Which operation has lowest impact on performance, min/max or modulus?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have created a grid with (N,N) cells on each direction, I want to check which points correspond to which cell, this is easy, however, there are some points that can be out of the grid and I want it to put then into one cell.

This is all done in the GPU, so my question is related to what will be the best operation to map the points lying out into a valid cell?

First option using max(0, min(N, cell.x)) which I believe will introduced divergence in the kernel. Second option using modulus (cell.x%N) which I believe is a very expensive operation to do in the GPU.

How can I decided which one to use?

Comment: Do you know anything about N? Modulos by powers of two are quite cheap, for example.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I guess in some cases that will imply increasing the memory needed right? But well ... the grid should not  be that big so it might be an option.

Comment: `First option using max(0, min(N, cell.x)) which I believe will introduced divergence in the kernel` Why do you think this will introduce divergence? These functions should map to very efficient branchless assembly such as `min.s32` and `max.s32`. No divergence there.

Comment: I didn't know that they map to efficient code which does not uses something like if-else structures. Do you know of any example where min/max is used and the performance is not affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPU has hardware instructions for integer `min()` and `max()`. If you dump the machine code from an executable compiled with nvcc using `cuobjdump --dump-sass` you can recognize these instructions, they are called `IMNMX` or `VMNMX` for example (the "mnmx" stands for "minimum or maximum", the selection between the two operations is by predicate).

For `N` that is a compile-time constant power of two, the modulo operation should map to a single `LOP.AND` instruction. For other compile-time constant values of `N` a small instruction sequence is emitted that typically involves integer multiplication and shifting. For variable `N`, i.e. determined at runtime, the modulo operation will basically require a full integer division which is at least 15 or so instructions.

So other than for the case of compile-time constant `N` being a power of two, clamping using `min()` and `max()` seems preferable over a modulo based solution from a performance perspective. However, unless your code performs this operation frequently and is limited by computational throughput, the kernel-level performance difference is likely small or possibly non-existent (if the code is memory bandwidth limited, for example).